# gsutil cp file upload is successful but gcloud log flags an error

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-logging

I'm in the process of uploading files from a VM to CLoud Storage.
use command line:
gsutil cp file.csv gs://xxxx/xxxxx/

My file has been uploaded successfully. The content of the log is completed. however Severity marked as error.
So is this a bug or not? if it is an error then how to fix this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HABkF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gsutil outputs progress / status info to stderr by design, to keep progress/status separated from data that's output to stdout.
refer to bellow post:
[question]: [result from "gsutil cp" is always in stderr, not stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387013/result-from-gsutil-cp-is-always-in-stderr-not-stdout)